# Generating sequences with coma seperated values

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to achieve something similar like cisco range commandos with ansible. in my case, I have tried the following:

```
- name: test playbook
  hosts: all 
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
       epg: "{{ lookup('env','EPG').split(',') }}"

  task:
  - debug:
      var:(item|int)
    with_sequence_ "{{ epg }}"
```

the input will be made by the user and can be something like:  10-13,20
in this case what I want to have just like the cisco IOS console :  10,11,12,13,20
instead, I get the following output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
task path: /opt2/jenkins/TEST/TEST interface.yaml:42
ok: [tst] => (item=10) => {
    "(item|int)": "10", 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "10"
}
ok: [tst] => (item=11) => {
    "(item|int)": "11", 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "11"
}
ok: [tst] => (item=12) => {
    "(item|int)": "12", 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "12"
}
ok: [tst] => (item=13) => {
    "(item|int)": "13", 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "13"
}
ok: [tst] => (item=1) => {
    "(item|int)": "1", 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "1"
}
ok: [tst] => (item=2) => {
    "(item|int)": "2", 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "2"
}
ok: [tst] => (item=3) => {
    "(item|int)": "3", 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "3"
... (so on up to 20)
```

How can I get only 10,11,12,13 and 20 if somebody can help me I will be glad. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to combine a list of jinja2 and Ansible filters. It's not easy but try this:

```
- name: test playbook
  hosts: all 
  vars:
       epg: "{{ lookup('env','EPG')}}"

  task:
  - debug:
      msg: "{% set LIST_EPG=[] %}{% for it in (epg.split(',')) %}{% set int1=it.split('-')[0] | int() %}{% if it.split('-') |length > 1 %}{% set int2=it.split('-')[1] | int() %}{% for i in range(int1, int2+1) %}{{ LIST_EPG.append(i|int) }}{% endfor %}{% endif %}{{ LIST_EPG.append(int1| int) }}{% endfor %}{{LIST_EPG|flatten|unique|join(',') }}"
```

Comment: Wow, that worked for me. Thanks a lot. Can you explain a bit about what you write up there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello, you start by creating a list var (LIST_EPG), then you split your initial env var (that give you a list), after, your split every item of your list (split ('-') and that give you a sublist of every items. And then, you use the range fonction to get to get every single integer between the two elements of the sublist and you add them to you list. After, the final list is flatten to obtain a single dimension list and you join off element with a comma separate.

Answer (score 0):

By splitting the comma separated list in `EPG` environment variable, you are creating an array/list in `epg`. So we need to iterate over this.

Consider environment variable as:

```
export EPG="10,11,12,13,20"
```

And reusing your `epg` variable:

```yaml
  vars:
    epg: "{{ lookup('env', 'EPG').split(',') }}"

  tasks:      
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ epg }}"
```

We can get this result:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=10) => {
    "msg": "10"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=11) => {
    "msg": "11"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=12) => {
    "msg": "12"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=13) => {
    "msg": "13"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=20) => {
    "msg": "20"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Seshadri_C, but the point of this question was that  if users, want to enter the variable as I wrote above, as another example 497-512,48,53 -->, in this case, the desired output is: 497,498,499,500,..,511,512,48,53